# Barra de navegação com mais de um dropbox no bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tentei criar uma barra de navegação onde tenha as seguintes colunas:
Home, Cadastro -> Cadastro de cliente e Consulta -> Consulta de cliente.
Quando estou no menu de consulta não consigo acessar o dropdown do cadastro de cliente. Porque?

```
    <title>Despesas</title>

    <!-- jquery - link cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap - link cdn -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Static navbar -->
<!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Cadastro
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="inserir_pessoa.php">Cadastro de clientes</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="pageSubmenu" href="#">Consultas
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="pageSubmenu">
                      <li><a href="consulta_clientes.php">Consulta de clientes</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="sair.php">Sair</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

            <table class="table">
        <thread>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Data de nascimento</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Excluir</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
            <?php

            foreach($grupo as $pessoa){ ?>

                <tr>
                    <td> <?=$pessoa["nome"]?> </td>
                    <td> <?=$pessoa["nascimento"]?> </td>
                    <td> <?=$pessoa["telefone"]?> </td>
                    <td> <?=$pessoa["endereco"]?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>


            <?php

            }

            ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Veja se esta retornando erro no `Console`.

Comment: Testei o seu código e funciona bem desde que o bootstrap.js seja carregado depois do jquery.

Comment: Estranho.  quando estou na nav Consulta não consigo acessar ela mesmo ou a cadastro de clientes. Não retorna nada no console. @Paulo o bootstrap está sendo carregado dps do jquery

Comment: Isso acontece depois de carregar no link, mudando de página? Está a carregar os ficheiros em todas as páginas ou só na primeira?

Comment: Carrego em todas.

Comment: Publique o seu HTML inteiro inclusive com a `<head>` vai facilitar para te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: Editei com o conteúdo inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

Em todas as páginas que contiverem esse menu, deverão ser carregados os ficheiros bootstrap.css, jquery.js e bootstrap.js ou as suas versões mínimas (.min.css ou .min.js)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

O jQuery.js deverá ser sempre carregado antes do Bootstrap.js

Comment: Estranho que estou carregando o bootstrap em todas as paginas, o jquery tbm